# Convert Xpath to CSS selector

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am struggling in converting the follow Xpath to CSS: "//form[@id=\'giftcard-form\']/div[3]/div/button". 
I know I could use the Xpath for my selenium JS but it doesn't work in my case for some odd reason. I was successful in converting an easier one and using its in the script but I can't get this one right.
Anyone can help?

Comment: try `#giftcard-form div:nth-child(3) button`

Comment: https://cssify.appspot.com/ `form#giftcard-form > div:nth-of-type(3) > div > button`

Comment: Welcome to SO. go through the guidelines on how to ask a good question.[Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Regarding your question paste the html snippet of the webelement that you want.

Comment: @Alok Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One should learn how to write css selectors, but a for a quick fix, try: [cssify](http://cssify.appspot.com/)

For example, I put in your xpath and it spit out: `form#giftcard-form > div:nth-of-type(3) > div > button`

Btw, you had an error in your xpath, it should be this: `//form[@id='giftcard-form']/div[3]/div/button`

Comment: any substitute? cssify isn't working any more :/

Comment: @MarkMayo, I might be late but check again. It's working.

Comment: yep, seems  back!

Comment: The link is not working, you can see error 500 in console log

Answer (score 2):

For *XPath* as:

```
//form[@id=\'giftcard-form\']/div[3]/div/button
```

The equivalent *CSS* would be:

```
form#giftcard-form>div:nth-of-type(3)>div>button
```