# Rewrite xpath OR condtion selector as css

Tags: xpath, css-selectors

I have this `xpath` OR condition selector that i like to rewrite as css

```
find_element(:xpath, "//input[@id='#{id_or_name}' or @name='#{id_or_name}'][@type='checkbox' or @type='radio']")
```

this is another, will this work?

```
find_element(:css, "input[id='{id_or_name}'][name='{id_or_name}'][type='checkbox'][type='radio']")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Xpath to CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53357654/convert-xpath-to-css-selector)

Comment: Not quite, my xpath selector has or condition and i like to write or condition in css.

Comment: Are the #s missing from your CSS example?